# ¿Como hacer dinámico un JsonProperty en c#?

Tags: json, asp.net, api

Hola compañeros Espero me puedan apoyar, estoy consumiendo un API diariamente y la consumo de esta manera:

```
        public static void GetTrafficByDay(string token)
    {
        var urlCompleta = GlobalCharlesAndKeith.APP_URL_HOST + GlobalCharlesAndKeith.APP_NAME + "/api" + "/traffic" + "/day/" + Global.date;

        using (var client = new RestClient(urlCompleta))
        {
            var request = new RestRequest(urlCompleta, Method.Get);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.ToString());

            RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            
        }
    }
```

Este es mi JSON que obtengo:

```
{
"store":"Aero - Culiacán"
,"traffic":
{
    "2023-04-11T12:00:00":1,
    "2023-04-11T13:00:00":2,
    "2023-04-11T14:00:00":11,
    "2023-04-11T15:00:00":14,
    "2023-04-11T16:00:00":7,
    "2023-04-11T17:00:00":18,
    "2023-04-11T18:00:00":9,
    "2023-04-11T19:00:00":17,
    "2023-04-11T20:00:00":8,
    "2023-04-11T21:00:00":1,
}
```

}

Este es mi modelo:

```
public class Root
{
    public string store { get; set; }
    public Traffic traffic { get; set; }
}

public class Traffic
{
    [JsonProperty("2023-04-11T12:00:00")]
    public int T120000 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2023-04-11T13:00:00")]
    public int T130000 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2023-04-11T14:00:00")]
    public int T140000 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2023-04-11T15:00:00")]
    public int T150000 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2023-04-11T16:00:00")]
    public int T160000 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2023-04-11T17:00:00")]
    public int T170000 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2023-04-11T18:00:00")]
    public int T180000 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2023-04-11T19:00:00")]
    public int T190000 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2023-04-11T20:00:00")]
    public int T200000 { get; set; }
}
```

Pero se estará consumiento diariamente, por lo que requiero cambiar el la fecha en el `JsonProperty`, mi pregunta es! Existe alguna manera de cambiarla diariamente? con un `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)` o alguna manera de poder hacerlo de otra manera? Espero me puedan apoyar.

Comment: Percibo que hay algo mal diseñado. ¿Tienes la documentación de la API a la que te estás conectando? Me gustaría verificar.

Comment: No, lamentablemente no me dieron nada de documentacion! Es por eso que estoy batallando bastante.

Comment: que tu api te de la fecha como nodo del json se me hace problema gigante de diseño, eso lo puedes modificar?

Comment: No es mi API, la estoy consumiendo de una empresa que trabaja junto con nosotros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiré que siempre va a haber Datetime y un valor entero como elementos del `Traffic`

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ApiResponse
{
    public string Store { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<DateTime, int> Traffic { get; set; }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"{
            ""store"": ""Aero - Culiacán"",
            ""traffic"": {
                ""2023-04-11T12:00:00"": 1,
                ""2023-04-11T13:00:00"": 2,
                ""2023-04-11T14:00:00"": 11,
                ""2023-04-11T15:00:00"": 14,
                ""2023-04-11T16:00:00"": 7,
                ""2023-04-11T17:00:00"": 18,
                ""2023-04-11T18:00:00"": 9,
                ""2023-04-11T19:00:00"": 17,
                ""2023-04-11T20:00:00"": 8,
                ""2023-04-11T21:00:00"": 1
            }
        }";

        ApiResponse response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(json);
        Console.WriteLine("Store: " + response.Store);
        Console.WriteLine("Traffic: ");
        foreach (var traffic in response.Traffic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(traffic.Key + ": " + traffic.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Genera como resultado:

```
Store: Aero - Culiacán
Traffic: 
4/11/2023 12:00:00 PM: 1
4/11/2023 1:00:00 PM: 2
4/11/2023 2:00:00 PM: 11
4/11/2023 3:00:00 PM: 14
4/11/2023 4:00:00 PM: 7
4/11/2023 5:00:00 PM: 18
4/11/2023 6:00:00 PM: 9
4/11/2023 7:00:00 PM: 17
4/11/2023 8:00:00 PM: 8
4/11/2023 9:00:00 PM: 1
```

Ejemplo en ejecución en https://dotnetfiddle.net/NpD9Lk