# ¿Como leer un objeto JSON?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Espero me puedan apoyar con este problema que tengo, quiero leer dato por dato en objeto de `traffic`.

-En mi primer foreach lo mando a un Jobject

-En el segundo separo el`store` y la lista de `traffic`, ahora me gustaria recorrer cada una del traffic, pero como podria hacerlo?

```
public static void LeerJson(string token)
    {

        string json = @"
        [{
            ""store"":""Aero - Culiacán""
            ,""traffic"":
            {
                ""2023-04-11T12:00:00"":1,
                ""2023-04-11T13:00:00"":2,
                ""2023-04-11T14:00:00"":11,
                ""2023-04-11T15:00:00"":14,
                ""2023-04-11T16:00:00"":7,
                ""2023-04-11T17:00:00"":18,
                ""2023-04-11T18:00:00"":9,
                ""2023-04-11T19:00:00"":17,
                ""2023-04-11T20:00:00"":8,
                ""2023-04-11T21:00:00"":1,
                ""2023-04-11T22:00:00"":0,
                ""2023-04-11T23:00:00"":0,
                ""2023-04-11T00:00:00"":0
            }
        }]";

        JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);

        foreach (JObject jsonObject in array.Children<JObject>())
        {
            /*Identificar las propiedades y sus valores*/
            foreach (JProperty property in jsonObject.Properties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(property.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Lo trate de hacer de la siguiente manera pero me volvio a mandar toda la lista:

```
JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);

        foreach (JObject jsonObject in array.Children<JObject>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(jsonObject.ToString());
            /*Identificar las propiedades y sus valores*/
            foreach (JProperty property in jsonObject.Properties())
            {
                if(property.Name == "traffic")
                {
                    foreach(JObject traffic in property.Children<JObject>())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(traffic.ToString());  
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(property.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Como hacer dinámico un JsonProperty en c#?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/590238/como-hacer-din%c3%a1mico-un-jsonproperty-en-c)

Comment: Muchas gracias, si responde a mi pregunta.

Comment: En ese caso, márcala como aceptada haciendo click en el check del costado de la respuesta. Saludos.